# How to use mouseover in <agm-map> angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I am using AgmMap for maps in angular 4 application. how to implement the mouseover event in agm-marker which shows info-window. I need to open info window on marker mouse hover. How can I retreive the infowindow instance in my function onMouseOver to open it?
This is my map.component.html file

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <agm-marker *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index"
          [latitude]="m.lat"
          [longitude]="m.lng"
          (markerClick)="clickedMarker(m, i)"
          [iconUrl]="m.iconUrl">
          <agm-info-window>{{m.label}}</agm-info-window>
  </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

and map.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AlertService, AuthenticationService } from '../_services/index';
import { Ng4DropdownModule } from 'ng4-material-dropdown';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
   moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})

export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
   title: string = 'My first AGM project';  
  lat: number = 51.673858;
  lng: number = 7.815982;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  markers: marker[] = [
      {
          lat: 51.673858,
          lng: 7.815982,
          label: 'Map A',
          draggable: true,
          iconUrl:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png'
      },
      {
          lat: 51.373858,
          lng: 7.215982,
          label: 'Map B',
          draggable: false,
          iconUrl:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png'
      },
      {
          lat: 51.723858,
          lng: 7.895982,
          label: 'Map C',
          draggable: true,
          iconUrl:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png'
      }
  ];

  constructor() {
   }

   clickedMarker(marker:marker, index:number)
   {
    console.log('Clicked Marker:'+ marker.label+' at index'+index);
   }


}
interface marker {
    lat: number;
    lng: number;
    label?: string;
    draggable: boolean;
    iconUrl?: string;
}
```

Can you please help me. how to implement  the mouseover event in AgmMap ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **`(mouseOver)="mouseOver($event)"`**

```
<agm-marker *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index" (markerClick)="clickedMarker(m,i)" [latitude]="m.lati" [longitude]="m.longi"
 (mouseOver)="mouseOver($event)">
</agm-marker>
```

Comment: Thank you @Sajeetharan , mouseOver event getting called .. Can you please tell me  how to show info window on mouse hover ?

Comment: just create a new instance and call show. mark if it helped

Comment: This is not helpful at all. It just shows how to handle mouseOver events but there is no info how to display info-window.

Comment: @Merdekar can you provide the code that have you used?

Comment: @John Based on the date of your question, I believe you have solve the issue.                           

<agm-marker *ngFor="let m of selectedData; let i = index"
   [latitude]="m.lat"
   [longitude]="m.lng"
   (markerClick)="clickedMarker(m, i)"
   [iconUrl]="m.iconUrl"
   (mouseOver)="mouseOver(infoWindow,m)"
   (mouseOut)="mouseOut(infoWindow,m)">           
   <agm-info-window #infoWindow  [latitude]="m.lat" [longitude]="m.lng" [isOpen]="m.info" >{{m.label}}<br> {{m.message}}</agm-info-window></agm-marker>

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code:

```html
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [usePanning]="true">
    <agm-marker *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index" [latitude]="m.lat" [longitude]="m.lng" (markerClick)="clickedMarker(m, i)" [iconUrl]="m.iconUrl" [openInfoWindow]="true" (mouseOver)="onMouseOver(infoWindow, $event)" (mouseOut)="onMouseOut(infoWindow, $event)">
        <agm-info-window [disableAutoPan]="false" #infoWindow>
            <div>
                <p [innerHTML]="m?.label"></p>
            </div>
        </agm-info-window>
    </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

ts Code:

```js
 onMouseOut(infoWindow) { infoWindow.close(); } onMouseOver(infoWindow) { infoWindow.open(); }
```